# How is braintree additionalInformation data used in measuring risk level of a transaction

Tags: braintree

I came to know that sending additionalInformation to Braintree as part of lookup java api
increases transactions without an authentication.

1. How is this additionalInformation used from braintree/issuing bank to measure the risk level of the transaction ?

Answer (score 0):

Each information you add is weighted and allows to compute a final scoring for this transaction.

You can adjust the threshold : https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/articles/guides/fraud-tools/basic/risk-threshold-rules

Also it is not braintree specific, you will find a sample of how those information are weighted here : https://help.bolt.com/merchants/references/dashboard-features/risk-scoring/